# Round a Magento Attribute in Admin Grid to the second Decimal

Tags: admin, magento-1, adminhtml, grid

Here is my remote files and their paths:

[image]

**app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php**

```
    <?php
class Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid{
    /**
     * override the _prepareCollection to add an other attribute to the grid
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('modify_catalog_labor')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer, use the line below
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer address, comment the line above and use the one below
            //->joinAttribute('mobile', 'customer_address/mobile', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        //code from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()
        //since calling parent::_prepareCollection will render the code above useless
        //and you cannot call in php parent::parent::_prepareCollection()
        if ($this->getCollection()) {

            $this->_preparePage();

            $columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
            $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
            $filter   = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);

            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $filter = $this->_defaultFilter;
            }

            if (is_string($filter)) {
                $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            }
            else if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
            else if(0 !== sizeof($this->_defaultFilter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($this->_defaultFilter);
            }

            if (isset($this->_columns[$columnId]) && $this->_columns[$columnId]->getIndex()) {
                $dir = (strtolower($dir)=='desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                $this->_columns[$columnId]->setDir($dir);
                $this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]);
            }

            if (!$this->_isExport) {
                $this->getCollection()->load();
                $this->_afterLoadCollection();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * override the _prepareColumns method to add a new column after the 'email' column
     * if you want the new column on a different position just change the 3rd parameter
     * of the addColumnAfter method to the id of your desired column
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumnAfter('modify_catalog_labor', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Labor'),
            'index'     => 'modify_catalog_labor',
            'type'      => 'decimal',
            'width'     => '240px',
            'renderer'  => 'sean_customergrid/adminhtml_grid_renderer_labor'
        ),'email');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerGrid>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomerGrid>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Renderer/Labor.php**

```
<?php

class Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Labor extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {

        return number_format($row->getModifyCatalogLabor(), 2);
    }

}
```

[image]

I have an attribute I display in the Admin Panel called "Labor" but is there any way I can easily round that number to the nearest 2 decimals?
5.0000 --> 5.00, 4.5000 --> 4.50

I'm receiving this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in
>   /home/makeyou/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php
>   on line 291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is all done using a mobile phone so haven't tested

> app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php

```
class Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{ 
    /** 
     * override the _prepareCollection to add an other attribute to the grid 
     * @return $this 
     */ 
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    { 
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection') 
            ->addNameToSelect() 
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email') 
            ->addAttributeToSelect('modify_catalog_labor') 
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at') 
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id') 
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer, use the line below 
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mobile') 
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer address, comment the line above and use the one below 
            //->joinAttribute('mobile', 'customer_address/mobile', 'default_billing', null, 'left') 
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left') 
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left') 
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left') 
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left') 
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left'); 

        $this->setCollection($collection); 

        //code from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection() 
        //since calling parent::_prepareCollection will render the code above useless 
        //and you cannot call in php parent::parent::_prepareCollection() 
        if ($this->getCollection()) { 
            $this->_preparePage(); 
            $columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort); 
            $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir); 
            $filter   = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null); 

            if (is_null($filter)) { 
                $filter = $this->_defaultFilter; 
            } 

            if (is_string($filter)) { 
                $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter); 
                $this->_setFilterValues($data); 
            } else if ($filter && is_array($filter)) { 
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter); 
            } else if(0 !== sizeof($this->_defaultFilter)) { 
                $this->_setFilterValues($this->_defaultFilter); 
            } 

            if (isset($this->_columns[$columnId]) && $this->_columns[$columnId]->getIndex()) { 
                $dir = (strtolower($dir)=='desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'; 
                $this->_columns[$columnId]->setDir($dir); 
                $this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]); 
            } 

            if (!$this->_isExport) { 
                $this->getCollection()->load(); 
                $this->_afterLoadCollection(); 
            } 
        } 
        return $this; 
    } 

    /** 
     * override the _prepareColumns method to add a new column after the 'email' column 
     * if you want the new column on a different position just change the 3rd parameter 
     * of the addColumnAfter method to the id of your desired column 
     */ 
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    { 
        $this->addColumnAfter('modify_catalog_labor', array( 
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Labor'), 
            'index'     => 'modify_catalog_labor', 
            'type'      => 'decimal', 
            'width'     => '240px', 
            'renderer' => 'customergrid/adminhtml_grid_renderer_labor', 
        ),'email'); 
        return parent::_prepareColumns(); 
    } 
}
```

> app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Renderer/Labor.php

```
class Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Labor extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{ 
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    { 
        return number_format($row->getModifyCatalogLabor(), 2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: is Rendor suppose to be Render? Not sure if typo or not

Comment: Yeah sorry as said using phone so auto correct

Comment: np also what is suppose to go here? just empty string?  '' => 'customergrid/adminhtml_grid_renderer_labour', and is it render or renderer here?

Comment: Sorry should be renderer in those quotes I'll update it

Comment: Please recheck code have fixed spelling mks

Comment: I have fixed spelling mistakes please recheck path and variable

Comment: I'll update what i've done so far and the error im getting

Comment: Sorry not easy on a phone my apologies

Comment: No worries! thanks for taking the time to help.  Here is what i've updated and the error its giving me

Comment: Go through and just make sure I have spelt it all correct as that error is issue with it not finding the renderer file if doesn't fix then send me a message and I'll fix it in morning for u

Comment: All the files seem to be there and I'm clearing the cache.  Does any of 'renderer' => 'customergrid/adminhtml_grid_renderer_labor' need to be capitalized?

Comment: It shouldn't do you can try or even add sean_customergrid instead if this doesn't work will look for u tomorrow bit late now

Comment: I've tried it all the different ways I still receive Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in /home/makeyou/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php on line 291

Comment: I've edited the question to show everything I have so far, I will continue to look for spelling/syntax errors

Comment: I figured out the problem but not sure why.  I deleted the file path and created app/code/local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Labor.php then changed 'renderer'  => 'Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Labor' and it works before I had the folder structure with grid in it and that wasn't allowing it to work?

Comment: Bit unsure as to why because I recreated your module today and implemented the same solution and worked first time. Very strange